# How would I get the full response from this Axios request?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roblox

I'm trying to get some data from a HTTP request (via Axios), however my issue is that I'm unsure of how I can get the "imageUrl" from it.

[image: axios request]

As you can see in the above image, this is the response I get. Below is the code I'm currently using:

```js
function getAvatarURL(userID) {
    axios.get(`https://thumbnails.roblox.com/v1/users/avatar-headshot?userIds=${userID}&size=420x420&format=Png&isCircular=false`)
        .then(r => {
            console.log(r.data)
        })
}
```

r.data.data returns what is in the image.

When I try and do `console.log(r.data.data.imageUrl)` is simply returns 'Undefined'

How would I go about getting the imageUrl from this?

Comment: `r.data.data[0].imageUrl` ?  The picture looks like an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is returning an Array of Objects.
You should first select the first element within the array to get the imageURL
You should change your console.log line to

```
console.log(r.data[0].imageUrl)
```

This should make it output as you expect it to be.